# Error in package function but not in command line R

Tags: r, seurat

I'm running this line of code from within an R package's function and am getting this error, but when I copy and paste the specific line of code in my command line, I don't get the error. Is there a package difference error? I'm not sure why this is failing within the R package, causing that function to halt.

Error in t.default(.): argument is not a matrix
when I run this line of code

```
counts <- Seurat::GetAssayData(object = obj, slot = "counts") %>% t()
```

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates both the error-free example and the one that throws the exception.  We will need test data too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I've tried `t`ransposing frames, named/unnamed lists, even frames with list-columns, and none of them produce an error. ***However***, I can reproduce this when `t` is passed `NULL` or an `environment`. When coding chains of expressions, it can seem convenient to not have to store intermediate objects, but when you see errors it is usually very advantageous to store them; in this case, I suspect that `Seurat::GetAssayData(.)` is returning something "wrong"-ish. Or something else than the types I've tried above.